# Getting data on facebook user using ID

Tags: objective-c, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode6

I need my APP to be able to get data on the user Facebook friends.
I managed to get the id of the Facebook friends but I'm stuck on getting their data.

I found an Objective C code that supposed to get the data, the problem is that I am using swift but I don't know how to convert the Objective C code to swift.

This is the code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}"
            parameters:params
            HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
            [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
            id result,
            NSError *error) {
            // Handle the result
            }];
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Did you look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561511/returning-data-from-function-swift

Comment: I already got the data on the user, I need to get data on his facebook friends

Comment: You can not get the data of the friends if they are not using the app.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift version would be

```
var request : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(
    graphPath: "/{user-id}/taggable_friends",
    parameters: params, 
    HTTPMethod: "GET"
)

request.startWithCompletionHandler { (
    connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!,
    result: AnyObject!,
    error:NSError!) -> Void in
    // Handle the result
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the birthday of a facebook user using his facebook id

Comment: You didn't say that. You said. "I don't know how to convert the Objective C code to swift." I did that. Maybe you should actually tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the birthday date of a facebook user by using his ID