# Facebook Graph API GET request - Should contain "fields" parameter (Swift, Facebook SDK v4.5.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

My iOS app uses Facebook's Graph API Request during sign up to get user information, which worked fine prior to upgrading to Facebook's newest SDK. After upgrading, I'm getting a runtime error stating: "FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter".

Here is the code:

```
func requestFacebook() {

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else if error == nil
        {
            let birthday : NSString = (result.valueForKey("birthday") as? NSString)!

            var currentDate = NSDate()
            var birthdayFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            birthdayFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
            var birthdayNSDate = birthdayFormatter.dateFromString(birthday as String)

            var userAge = self.calculateAge(birthdayNSDate!)

            PFUser.currentUser()!["age"] = userAge

            var facebookID: NSString = (result.valueForKey("id") as? NSString)!
            var pictureURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"

            var URLRequest = NSURL(string: pictureURL)
            var URLRequestNeeded = NSURLRequest(URL: URLRequest!)

            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(URLRequestNeeded, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    var picture = PFFile(data: data)
                    PFUser.currentUser()!["picture"] = picture
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            var userPicture:PFFile = PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("picture") as! PFFile
                            userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData, error) -> Void in
                                if error == nil {

                                    self.meProfileImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                                    var userName:String = PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("username") as! String
                                    var userAge:Int = PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("age") as! Int
                                    self.meLabel.text = "\(userName), \(userAge)"

                                    self.findFriends()

                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            println(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

The error message is at the line:

```
let birthday : NSString = (result.valueForKey("birthday") as? NSString)!
```

This code ran perfectly fine before upgrading to Facebook's SDK v4.5.1, but I don't know what to change to make this work now. Huge thanks to anyone that can help me!

Answer (score 123, accepted):

this line needs a parameters value that is NOT nil

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
```

I'll expand more, for example, and this is psuedo code of sorts:

so for ObjC it would be this, for example, so the the above would read the following:

```
parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name"}
```

In swift it would be something similar

something like this:

```
parameters:["fields": "email"]
```

This is for just two fields, and again it's psuedo code, but you need to specify the parameters

---

### **UPDATE:**

**Im adding this update to show folks where you find the parameters for the fields as described above, here's a quick link:**

### Here's the Paramters field info (this should stay roughly static with FBSDK, some of this is "core" which means it won't really change that much, but I'll update whenever I can):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

The format of the info below is the following, sort of, I just did this quickly:

**"parameter"**  **"type"**

**"description"**

> **id** numeric string
>
> The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app
>   and cannot be used across different apps. Our upgrade guide provides
>   more information about app-specific IDs
>
> **about** string
>
> The About Me section of this person's profile
>
> **age_range** AgeRange
>
> The age segment for this person expressed as a minimum and maximum
>   age. For example, more than 18, less than 21.
>
> **bio** string
>
> The person's bio
>
> **birthday** string
>
> The person's birthday. This is a fixed format string, like MM/DD/YYYY.
>   However, people can control who can see the year they were born
>   separately from the month and day so this string can be only the year
>   (YYYY) or the month + day (MM/DD)
>
> **context** UserContext
>
> Social context for this person
>
> **currency** Currency
>
> The person's local currency information
>
> **devices** list
>
> The list of devices the person is using. This will return only iOS and
>   Android devices
>
> **education** list
>
> The person's education
>
> **email** string
>
> The person's primary email address listed on their profile. This field
>   will not be returned if no valid email address is available
>
> **favorite_athletes** list
>
> Athletes the person likes
>
> **favorite_teams** list
>
> Sports teams the person likes
>
> **first_name** string
>
> The person's first name
>
> **gender** string
>
> The gender selected by this person, male or female. This value will be
>   omitted if the gender is set to a custom value
>
> **hometown** Page
>
> The person's hometown
>
> **inspirational_people** list
>
> The person's inspirational people
>
> **install_type** enum
>
> Install type
>
> **installed** bool
>
> Is the app making the request installed?
>
> **interested_in** list
>
> Genders the person is interested in
>
> **is_shared_login** bool
>
> Is this a shared login (e.g. a gray user)
>
> **is_verified** bool
>
> People with large numbers of followers can have the authenticity of
>   their identity manually verified by Facebook. This field indicates
>   whether the person's profile is verified in this way. This is distinct
>   from the verified field
>
> **languages** list
>
> Facebook Pages representing the languages this person knows
>
> **last_name** string
>
> The person's last name
>
> **link** string
>
> A link to the person's Timeline
>
> **location** Page
>
> The person's current location as entered by them on their profile.
>   This field is not related to check-ins
>
> **locale** string
>
> The person's locale
>
> **meeting_for** list
>
> What the person is interested in meeting for
>
> **middle_name string
>
> The person's middle name
>
> **name** string
>
> The person's full name
>
> CoreDefault
>
> **name_format** string
>
> The person's name formatted to correctly handle Chinese, Japanese, or
>   Korean ordering
>
> **payment_pricepoints** PaymentPricepoints
>
> The person's payment pricepoints
>
> **test_group** unsigned int32
>
> Platform test group
>
> **political** string
>
> The person's political views
>
> **relationship_status** string
>
> The person's relationship status
>
> **religion** string
>
> The person's religion
>
> **security_settings** SecuritySettings
>
> Security settings
>
> **significant_other** User
>
> The person's significant other
>
> **sports** list
>
> Sports this person likes
>
> **quotes** string
>
> The person's favorite quotes
>
> **third_party_id** string
>
> A string containing an anonymous, but unique identifier for the
>   person. You can use this identifier with third parties
>
> **timezone** float (min: -24) (max: 24)
>
> The person's current timezone offset from UTC
>
> **token_for_business** string
>
> A token that is the same across a business's apps. Access to this
>   token requires that the person be logged into your app. This token
>   will change if the business owning the app changes
>
> **updated_time** datetime
>
> Updated time
>
> **shared_login_upgrade_required_by** datetime
>
> The time that the shared loginneeds to be upgraded to Business Manager
>   by
>
> **verified** bool
>
> Indicates whether the account has been verified. This is distinct from
>   the is_verified field. Someone is considered verified if they take any
>   of the following actions:
>
> ```
> Register for mobile
> Confirm their account via SMS
> Enter a valid credit card
> ```
>
> **video_upload_limits** VideoUploadLimits
>
> Video upload limits
>
> **viewer_can_send_gift** bool
>
> Can the viewer send a gift to this person?
>
> **website** string
>
> The person's website
>
> **work** list
>
> Details of a person`s work experience
>
> **public_key** string
>
> The person's PGP public key
>
> **cover** CoverPhoto

---

### Also, here's the current "Edge" stuff: The format for "Edge' stuff is this, roughly, I did this quickly:

**"Edge"**

**"Description"**

> **favorite_requests**
>
> Developers' favorite requests to the Graph API
>
> **request_history**
>
> Developers' Graph API request history
>
> **accounts**
>
> Facebook Pages this person administers/is an admin for
>
> **achievements**
>
> Achievements made in Facebook games
>
> **adaccounts**
>
> The advertising accounts to which this person has access
>
> **adaccountgroups**
>
> Ad account groups
>
> **adcontracts**
>
> The person's ad contracts
>
> **admined_groups**
>
> Groups the user admins
>
> **adnetworkanalytics**
>
> Insights data for the person's Audience Network apps
>
> **albums**
>
> The photo albums this person has created
>
> **apprequests**
>
> This person's pending requests from an app
>
> **apprequestformerrecipients**
>
> App requests
>
> **books**
>
> The books listed on this person's profile
>
> **domains**
>
> The domains the user admins
>
> **events**
>
> Events for this person. By default this does not include events the
>   person has declined or not replied to
>
> **family**
>
> This person's family relationships.
>
> **stream_filters**
>
> A list of filters that can be applied to the News Feed edge
>
> **friendlists**
>
> The person's custom friend lists
>
> **ids_for_business**
>
> Business entities can claim ownership of multiple apps using the
>   Business Manager. This edge returns the list of IDs that this user has
>   in any of those other apps
>
> **invitable_friends**
>
> A list of friends that can be invited to install a Facebook Canvas app
>
> **games**
>
> Games this person likes
>
> **groups**
>
> The Facebook Groups that the person belongs to
>
> **likes**
>
> All the Pages this person has liked
>
> **movies**
>
> Movies this person likes
>
> **music**
>
> Music this person likes
>
> **objects**
>
> Objects
>
> **permissions**
>
> The permissions that the person has granted this app
>
> **photos**
>
> Photos the person is tagged in or has uploaded
>
> **picture**
>
> The person's profile picture
>
> **tagged_places**
>
> List of tagged places for this person. It can include tags on videos,
>   posts, statuses or links
>
> **promotable_domains**
>
> All the domains user can promote
>
> **promotable_events**
>
> All the events which user can promote.
>
> **taggable_friends**
>
> Friends that can be tagged in content published via the Graph API
>
> **television**
>
> TV shows this person likes
>
> **videos**
>
> Videos the person is tagged in or uploaded
>
> **video_broadcasts**
>
> Video broadcasts from this person
>
> **applications**
>
> The Facebook apps that this person is a developer of.
>
> **checkins**
>
> The checkins this person has made.
>
> **feed**
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by
>   this person.
>
> **friendrequests**
>
> A person's pending friend requests.
>
> **friends**
>
> A person's friends.
>
> **home**
>
> A person's Facebook homepage feed.
>
> **inbox**
>
> A person's Facebook Messages inbox.
>
> **locations**
>
> A feed of posts and photos that include location information and in
>   which this person has been tagged. This is useful for constructing a
>   chronology of places that the person has visited.
>
> **mutualfriends**
>
> The list of mutual friends between two people.
>
> **notifications**
>
> The unread Facebook notifications that a person has.
>
> **outbox**
>
> A person's Facebook Messages outbox.
>
> **questions**
>
> The questions that a person has created.
>
> **scores**
>
> The scores this person has received from Facebook Games that they've
>   played.
>
> **subscribers**
>
> The profiles that are following this person.
>
> **subscribedto**
>
> The profile that this person is following.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but that syntax for swift doesn't work. I tried parameters:["fields" : ["id", "birthday", "picture"] but that doesn't work either

Comment: thats why I changed the answer, try it now

Comment: no u tried this one you said :["fields" : ["id", "birthday", "picture"]  thats not what the answer shows

Comment: Oh, there's a miscommunication here. I tried the updated answer FIRST. Never saw the original answer. Then I tried the one in my comment as an ALTERNATIVE. Both didn't work.

Comment: And I put the right amount of brackets in my code, just mistyped in my comment.

Comment: ahh have you tried this? :["fields" : "id", "name"] the second colon should have been a comma

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I think it's the parameters:["fields" : ["id", "birthday", "picture"]] one (being that is the only one that doesn't give a compile error), but I could not be using valid fields...? Where can I find a list of fields that work?

Comment: Yeah, so try this one as well really quick  ["fields": "email"] there's a lot of people struggling with this using Swift, this seems to work and it's a start

Comment: from that one, we can expand it to something like this  ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name"]    HOPEFULLY, ... this one here SHOULD be the correct one but try the  ["fields": "email"] first

Comment: The "email" field worked as a start, thanks! I'll figure it out from here.

Comment: No problem, Swift is still very new so it's hard to "nail" down what needs to happen, if you need additional help, just ask

Comment: I am having same problem and here is my request looks like but still nil for email FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email"]) and I am requesting for email permissions permissions = ["public_profile", "email"] so not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Larcerax Thank you for the answer, it worked for me. Do you happen to know the parameter key values I can ask (email and name being a couple of them)? I tried Facebook's API documentation, but it was easier to find a unicorn than to find their answer!

Comment: @Loxx My request runs but I'm not able to access the key-value pair from the details of the result    `graphRequest.start({ (httpResponse, result) in
                    print("\(httpResponse.debugDescription)")
                    print("\(result)")
                })`

Comment: Can't we get phone number? I tried with parameter "phone" but it shows error

Comment: Does anyone know why this is utilizing v2.4? Or maybe just by using fields, you force it v2.9 nowadays?

Answer (score 26):

use "fields" as Key and then comma separate your values

```
let params = ["fields": "email, friends"]
```

Comment: Something broken, i can't get email

Comment: @adubey did you get the email?

Comment: Yes, I did. Found out it was an issue on Facebook side. The account I created on Facebook when I logged into it they didn't have my email so when I was retrieving it I was getting nothing. I created new account now so it works.

Comment: emails can be null in the facebook system. FYI.

Answer (score 12):

In Obj-C insert in the logInWithReadPermissions method:

```
parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, email"}
```

if you leave nil in parameters you only receive id and name in the result object, although you have set for example:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"email", @"public_profile"];
```

It´s not very clear in the documentation, hope it can helps.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but adding field options would generate a request error when fetching the user photo.  I solved this problem by adding a simple `parameters:@{@"fields": @""}` to the code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/picture"]
                              parameters:@{@"fields": @""}
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // success
    } else {
        // fail
    }}
];
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift, you can declare multiple parameters like this:

```
let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, gender, picture"])
```