# Graph Path and Parameters for getting facebook friends list in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I'm using the below code to get the friends list,

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters:["fields": "friendlists"]);
    fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            print("Friends are : \(result)")

        } else {

            print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");

        }
    }
```

It's always returning empty array.

**OutPut:**

```
 Friends are : {
 data =     (
 );
}
```

If I try sending a simple call to /me/friends, `FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/friends", parameters:nil)` an error logged as below,

```
FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for //me/friends should contain an explicit "fields" parameter.
```

So I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32056353/756941) for the above Parameters.

I authorized the app with two facebook users, both of them are friends in facebook, But I can't see their details in the response.

Still, empty array is returning.

Anyone please check whether the graph path and parameters I mentioned in the code is correct.

The privacy settings in the facebook account for friends list is public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between "friends" and "friendlists". What you want to get is the list of "friends", not the "friendlists". You don´t need the "fields" parameter for that, a simple call to `/me/friends` is enough.

That being said, you can only get friends who authorized your App too, so if none of your friends authorized your App, you will get an empty array. Of course you need to authorize with the `user_friends` permission, and your friends must authorize your App with that permission too.

Comment: Ok I understood. I need to get all my friends email address even if they are not authorized my app. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that is of course not possible. As already said, can not get “all friends” any more – and you can not get the email addresses of random users at all. You can only get the email for users that log into your app and grant it the according permission themselves.

Comment: exactly, what CBroe said. you can only get the email of users who authorized your App with the "email" permission.

Comment: Please see my edited question, if I simply call /me/friends, it's not working. I authorized with two facebook users, both of them are friends in facebook, But I can't see their details in the response.

Comment: it only works if both friends authorized the app with user_friends

Answer (score 2):

You can get only authorized friends with your application.

> Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app.

Check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0) for deatiled information.

You can get only count of friends linked to your account, but you can not get any other detail of friends without permission.

[image]