# How do I get larger a image from Facebook album using Graph API iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried several ways to get larger images from Facebook Graph API, but I have not succeeded.

1. I don't really know how this ***Parameters*** work. So will you explain me that too?
2. Also I need to know how to grab the larger images. 
   I first get the album I'd and then pictures ID and then I fetch the image of the album.
3. What is the best picture size to get for iPhone 6?

   ```
   let parameters = ["fields": "picture.height(400).width(200)"]
   FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/{picture-id}", parameters: parametes, HTTPMethod: "GET")
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Graph API to get different size of images. You need to have picture id. You request it like this:

**/{*picture-id*}?fields=width,height,images**

Since above query returns JSON data. In that data **"images"** contains different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If the picture you get with `picture?type=large` is not big enough, I suggest you try with `picture?width=9999` for example.

The code would be:

```
let requestPicture = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "{user_id}/picture?width=9999&redirect=false", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031677/facebook-graph-api-get-request-should-contain-fields-parameter-swift-faceb) SO thread may be useful to you regarding parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that the large image is 200x200. I don't think anyone would refer to that as large.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the user's ID and they have given appropriate permissions, you can do:

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(userId)/picture?type=large")
  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl!) {
        let profilePicture = UIImage(data: data)
  }
}
```

You can also do any of the enum values: small, normal, album, large, square as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/). Better yet, you can use AFNetworking to load the image in the background with a placeholder image, which handles caching and everything for you. See [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h) for more details, specifically setImageWithURL.

Comment: Oh this is good useful information. Thank you. Can you explain more about parameter? And I am looking for album larger picture?

Answer (score 0):

From the login or by making the basic graph request with me you can get user-id and from that user-id you may try this

You can try like this:

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/{user-id}/picture?redirect=false&type=large", parameters: nil);
                    fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            print("Result is : \(result)")
                            /* this will return the data of the image which you can use with imageview with data method {
                              "data": "ProfilePictureSource",
                               "paging": {}
                            }*/

                        } else {

                            println("Error Getting Friends \(error)");

                        }
          }
```

For the fields which you have pass `picture.height and picture.width` is used to specify the image with which is return to you in the response

You can use both types of size reference :

Predefined sizes:  small, normal, large, square.
Custom size: specify the width and height of the image you want

For more information you can check the facebook doc : [Facebook doc:User Profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture://)

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am looking for Album picture(larger). I am using album id and then getting picture id.